# How do I see that $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} 5/4-x-\sqrt {(x-5/4)^2 -1} = 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

How do I see that $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} 5/4-x-\sqrt {(x-5/4)^2 -1} = 0$$ ?

I see that the function is continuous, so I can take the limit under the square root, but this doesn't help me much here, because the limit is evaluated at infinity ?

Also, I've tried looking for an upper bound that goes towards $-1$ as $t$ goes towards $-\infty$.

Can someone help ?

Comment: May be you could simplify the problem using an appropriate change of variable (I suppose it is simple to see) and extract one term from the radical and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't “take the limit under the square root”, because this is in the form $\infty-\infty$, so some more work is needed.

I usually advice doing the substitution $t=-x$ so you have a limit at $\infty$ that's arithmetically easier, but in this case it's much better to use
$$
t=\frac{5}{4}-x
$$
so we get
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}t-\sqrt{t^2-1}
$$
The standard path is to remove the square roots:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}t-\sqrt{t^2-1}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{(t-\sqrt{t^2-1})(t+\sqrt{t^2-1})}{t+\sqrt{t^2-1}}
$$
Develop the numerator and finish.

---

Why is it “arithmetically easier” to cope with limits at $\infty$ than at $-\infty$? If you have something like
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(\dots+\sqrt{x^2(\cdots)}\;\right)
$$
the correct way to take out $x^2$ from the square root is
$$
\sqrt{x^2(\cdots)}=-x\sqrt{\cdots\mathstrut}
$$
because we can suppose to be working in an interval where $x<0$. This is often cause for mistakes. If we have made the transformation $t=-x$, we'd have no problem in taking out $t$ from the square root.

Comment: You are right, the limit should be $0$. I've corrected. Thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}5/4-x-\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1}$$$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{(5/4-x-\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1})(5/4-x+\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1})}{5/4-x+\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{(5/4-x)^2-(x-5/4)^2+1}{5/4-x+\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1}}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{1}{5/4-x+\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1}}$$
$$=\lim_{\color{red}{t\to +\infty}}\frac{1}{5/4+t+\sqrt{(-t-5/4)^2-1}}\ \ \ (\text{set $t=-x$})$$
$$=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{1/t}{5/(4t)+1+\sqrt{(1+5/(4t))^2-1/(t^2)}}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If we have a limit where $x$ is going to negative infinity, we can make the substitution to let $x = -x$. Then it follows that as $\lim_{x\to -\infty} x = \lim_{x\to \infty} -x$

Therefore, our limit now becomes:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5}{4} + x - \sqrt{\left(-x - \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1} = \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5}{4} + x - \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}$$

First, let's note that, for the constant in this limit, it's simiply going to equal $\frac{5}{4}$.

Now, we can focus on the variable terms:

$$\frac{5}{4} + \left[\lim_{x\to \infty} x - \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}\right]$$

For the limit, if we multiply the top and bottom by its conjugate:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\left(x - \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}\right)*\left(x + \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}\right)}{x + \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}} = \frac{x^2 - \left(\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1\right)}{x + \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}} = \frac{-\frac{5}{2}x - \frac{25}{16} + 1}{x + \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}}$$

Now, we can divide each of your terms by $x$, or the $\sqrt{x^2}$:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{5}{2}x - \frac{25}{16} + 1}{x + \sqrt{\left(x + \frac{5}{4}\right)^2 - 1}} =\frac{-\frac{5}{2} - \frac{25}{16x} + \frac{1}{x}}{1 + \sqrt{1 + \frac{5}{2x} + \frac{25}{16x^2} - \frac{1}{x^2}}} = -\frac{5}{4}$$

Therefore, our final answer is:

$$\frac{5}{4} - \frac{5}{4} = 0$$

In fact, we find that the limit is $0$, not $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the term $x-5/4$. So you get $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} -(x-5/4) \left( 1+\frac{\sqrt{(x-5/4)^2-1}}{x-5/4} \right)$$.
Putting the term $(x-5/4)$ under the square root we obtain $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} -(x-5/4) \left( 1-\sqrt{ \frac{ (x-5/4)^2-1}{(x-5/4)^2} }  \right)$$ where the minus before the square root appear because x goes to minus infinity. Then $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} -(x-5/4) \left( 1-\sqrt{ 1-\frac{ 1}{(x-5/4)^2} }  \right)$$.
Using the well known limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=a$ we get $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} (x-5/4) \left( \sqrt{ 1-\frac{ 1}{(x-5/4)^2} }-1  \right)=(x-5/4)\left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(x-5/4)^2}\right)$$ that goes to zero as $x \to -\infty$